# How to display many items in turns

Tags: c#, .net, razor, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have a slideshow and a video in a razor component. I want to display them in turn(one after another) i mean for example first show the slideshow and then the video and repeat it forever or is it possible to add a video in the carousel.
I will be thankful if somebody help.

Here is the HTML code:

```
 @page "/home"
    
    @using Components;
    @using System.Collections;
    @using System.IO;
    @using MimeMapping;
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    
    @inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment
    
    
    <div class="text-center">
    
        <TemplatedCarousel Items="AssetImages" TItem="ImageFile" AutoScrollInterval="5" OnCarouselItemClicked="OnCarouselItemClicked" ShowNavigation="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img class="d-block center" src="@GetImageSource(@context)" alt="@context.FileName">
            </ItemTemplate>
        </TemplatedCarousel>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="text-center">
    
        <video controls="controls" autoplay muted>
            <source src="Video/Sample_small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
```

Here is c# code:

```
@code
{ List<ImageFile> AssetImages
    {
        get
        {
            List<ImageFile> imagesToReturn = new List<ImageFile>();

            var assetFiles = Environment.WebRootFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("Assets");

            foreach (var assetFile in assetFiles)
            {
                ImageFile imageFile = new ImageFile()
                {
                    FileName = assetFile.Name,
                    MimeType = MimeMapping.MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping(assetFile.Name)
                };

                imageFile.FileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(assetFile.PhysicalPath);
                imagesToReturn.Add(imageFile);
            }

            return imagesToReturn;
        }
    }

    private string GetImageSource(ImageFile imageFile)
    {
        string imageSrc = imageFile.Url;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageFile.Url) && imageFile.FileContent?.Length > 0)
        {
            imageSrc = imageFile.Base64Image;
        }

        return imageSrc;
    }

    void OnCarouselItemClicked(object sender, int indexClicked)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Carousel Index Clicked: {indexClicked}");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this going to be based on time or something else? You already have a carousel - why don't you put everything in that?

Comment: I already put images in carousel, there is a folder with name of Assets in my project as images are there. I just want to display carousel, video and an image one by one not all of them together.

Comment: Right but you have a carousel component that does that. Why not use it?

Comment: I did, but video is not displaying in the carousel, i set the video in Assets folder. it show an empty frame and change to another slide.

Comment: The carousel component - is that yours or from a nuget? Can it accept `<Item>` markup - I was assuming it would and you could wrap the three "things" in an outer carousel - to switch between them `<TemplatedCarousel><Item #1><TemplatedCarousel of images></Item #1><Item #2><img thing></Item #2><Item #3><Video thing></Item #3></TemplatedCarousel>` as a rough guide

Comment: Otherwise - you could keep track of what you want to display and put the three items in a `switch` statement so you only display one at a time - depending on the current state

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cycle through UI fragments, you can do something like this

```cs
@code
{
    int state=1;    
}
<button @onclick=@(_=> state = 1 + (++state % 3))>Next</button>
@switch(state)
{
    case 1:
        <h1>Carousel here</h1>
        break;
    case 2: 
        <h1>Image here</h1>
        break;
    case 3:
        <h1>Video here</h1>
        break;
}
```

The button is just there to cycle the state - anything could do that - a timer, some other interaction/event.

Then you just display whatever you want to display for each state

Sample : https://blazorfiddle.com/s/tozxddow